# Understanding the construction 〜にも〜にも

Tags: particle-に

> 反転十香が、自分たちに何かをさせようとしている。ーーそれならば確かに筋が通った。突然の反転十香の登場**にも**、そして邪魔者であるはずの士道たちを放置したこと**にも**。

Are the sentences some kind of inversion? Namely, the normal order is 突然の反転十香の登場にも、そして邪魔者であるはずの士道たちを放置したことにも確かに筋が通った? If so, why is にも used rather than just も? What would be the function of the に?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is correct. The use of に indeed sounds weird to me. The author probably thinks 〜に筋が通る is a good collocation for the meaning of 〜に納得がいく. I disagree.

Comment: I don't think ～ことに筋が通る is strange. There are many [examples online](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E7%AD%8B%E3%81%8C%E9%80%9A%E3%82%8B%22).

Comment: @naruto: For me, 〜に筋が通る means what’s marked by に is consistent. It works well with such a thing as a story, an argument, etc. The first three search results all pointing to the same source doesn’t seem a good sign when it comes to how common the phrase is.

Comment: @naruto Thank you both. So 〜に筋が通る should be memorized as a set phrase? And what exactly is the function of the  に?

Comment: @chinoalpha: Same as in 穴に糸が通る.

Comment: Thank you again. I’m not familiar with the expression 穴に糸が通る. Does it mean “to get the thread through the eye of the needle”?

Comment: @chinoalpha: Yes, except that would be a more correct translation of 穴に糸を通す (transitive) than of 穴に糸が通る (intransitive). Other examples include 肉に串が通る and 山梨にリニアモーターカーが通る.